# Change node configuration dashboard UI settings

Tags: nodes, 8

While creating a node content Drupal 8 provides the following settings.

[image]

I want the *URL path setting* tab to be open by default.

I want to achieve it through the Drupal 8 backend customization settings (more preferable) or even Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Notice that you are simply stating facts, without asking any explicit question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have mentioned I want the URL path setting tab to be open by default.

Comment: You didn't said what exactly is your problem, what you don't understand, and what you tried. "I want" is a request, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the UI, you need code.

You could attach some JS to open it, but it's much easier to create a module with a form_alter and then you can make the element expanded by default.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path%21path.module/function/path_form_node_form_alter/8.2.x defines the element, you can see that it defaults to open when there is an alias already.